# jquery autocomplete and jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery

I have a question about how to collaborate auto complete with UI dialog:

1. There is an input text which enables autocomplete (the data is not a simple string array, so it needs to be parsed). This job is well done:

   ```
   <input type="text" id="styleno" name="styleno" >

   $("#styleno").autocomplete("${suggest}", {
                   parse:function(raw){
                var parsed = [];
                for (var i=0; i < raw.model.length; i++) {    

                   var row = raw.model[i];
                   parsed.push({
                       data: row,
                      value: row,
                     result: row.styleNo
                   });
                }
                return parsed;

           },
           formatMatch: function(row, i, max) {
                    return row.styleNo;
                   },
                   formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {
                   //

                           return  data.id+data.styleNo;
                   }
           });
   ```
2. When a result is selected from the suggested list, I want to open a dialog, populate somethings from the parsed the result. So I use the "result" function:

   ```
   $("#styleno").result(function(data,values){
           $('#itemDiv').dialog('open');
   }
   ```

   The dialog is opened, but the focus is kept on the auto suggested input field (`<input type="text" id="styleno" name="styleno" >`). So I use this code:

   ```
   $("#styleno").trigger("unautocomplete");
   ```

   Now the dialog is fine, but the input field lost its autosuggestion capability.

What shall I do? According to the selected item from suggestion list, then pop up a dialog with some input field. After user fills the field in the dialog, close it, get back to auto suggested field still use the auto suggestion function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure it works like this, but you might try the following:

```
$("#styleno").blur();
```

Sounds like the event you are looking for.

Comment: Hi mate,
$("#styleno").blur(); works well in IE7 and Firefox.

However, it does not work in IE8. The autosuggest input field won't let its focus go:(

Do you have any idea about the weired problem in IE8?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't have IE8 at the moment, so I can't test it to play and a quick search on Google turned up nothing useful. Perhaps ask a new question with the specifics and see if anyone else has an idea :-)